# Netcat as UDP Client does not receive response packets from Arduino Wifi Shield. Simple C UDP Client Does. Why?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, arduino, client-server

I am testing out the [WiFi UDP Send and Receive String](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiSendReceiveUDPString) example Arduino code with the Arduino Wifi Shield (newest firmware update Mar. 2013), and I'm getting behaviour I cannot explain.

## Expected Operation

The Arduino receives UDP packets on its own local arbitrary port from another computer on the router - remoteIP:remotePort. It acknowledges to the client that it has received the packet by sending a UDP packet of its own back to remoteIP:remotePort.

I thought I would test by using netcat. netcat will send the UDP packets and Arduino receives, but netcat is not receiving the packets sent by Arduino. The blame lies in netcat, because I used a [Simple C UDP Client](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-client.c) and that client WOULD receive the Arduino server UDP responses.

Does anyone know what extra cruft is in Netcat that would be causing this? I've noticed similar issues when using netcat on TCP to interact with servers using unknown protocols. The interaction was not "raw," things were not showing up that seemingly should be, like these UDP packets from the UDP server. Is it something about the makeup of the UDP packets that does not satisfy netcat?

[Arduino UDP Server Code](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiSendReceiveUDPString)

[Simple C UDP Client Code](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-client.c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between your code and nc is, that you use an unconnected socket and specify the recipient within the sendto call, while nc will use a connected socket. This means, that your socket will accept replies from any address, while nc will only accept replies from the same IP **and port** where it send the request to. I don't know about the Arduino udp library you use, but from a short look at the code I don't see anything like using a udp connection, so I assume that my theory is correct. If you use tcpdump/wireshark this is what I expect you to see with your client at IP cip and port cport and Arduino at IP cip and port 32000 (matching your example C-code):

```
--> request from cip:cport to   aip:32000
<-- reply to     cip:cport from aip:random_port
```

But what you need if you want it to work with nc is

```
--> request from cip:cport to   aip:32000
<-- reply to     cip:cport from aip:32000
```

Comment: I took a quick look at the Library source code for the WifiShield UDP Server, there is no obvious way to set the server to send the UDP packets from its listener port. Seems the answers leads into low level land. Since my ultimate solution does not involve using the shield as a UDP server, I am letting it go. Good luck to anybody else!!

Comment: I have one more question. Outside of modifying netcat source code, can netcat be set to use unconnected sockets instead of connected sockets? I couldn't find anything on it myself (man pages, google)